# How to refund bitcoin after wallet recovery?

Tags: lost-bitcoins

I lost my bitcoin balance after I forgot my wallet password in blockchain. Although I managed to get my wallet (same wallet with the same security phrase) recovered,my balance showed 0. Where did my bitcoin go ? Can I access them again?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "same wallet"?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you said you lost your password to your blockchain wallet, and since you have the wallet and the security passphrase,
then actually you should check the btc address in which you have the fund on blockchain.info to see if your actually balance is there

Comment: Thanks for your answer , what do you mean by btc address ? Do you mean my wallet address?

Comment: yes your wallet address